# Friend Table with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working the friend table with mysql. I want to get friend userid and username form current username.

```
friend
=======
- id
- uid
- fid

Sample Data 
===========
id  uid  fid
1    1    2
2    3    1

user
====    
- id
- username

Sample Data 
===========
id username
1  saturngod
2  snow
3  John
```

My current code is

```
SELECT `user`.id,`user`.username FROM friend
INNER JOIN User
ON user.id = friend.uid
WHERE friend.fid = ( SELECT `id` FROM `User` WHERE `username`='saturngod')

UNION

SELECT `user`.id,`user`.username FROM friend
INNER JOIN User
ON user.id = friend.fid
WHERE friend.uid =  ( SELECT `id` FROM `User` WHERE `username`='saturngod')
```

It's working. I got the friend list. However, I feel , the sql is so long.

Can I reduce this sql and can we write without UNION in sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You have already joined the tables, so the subselect is not needed.

```
  SELECT u.id,u.username 
  FROM user u
  INNER JOIN friend f ON (u.id = f.uid)
  WHERE u.username='saturngod'
UNION ALL
  SELECT u2.id,u2.username 
  FROM user u
  INNER JOIN friend f ON (u.id = f.uid)
  INNER JOIN user u2 ON (u2.id = f.fid)
  WHERE u.username='saturngod'
```

Or you can do:

```
  SELECT 
    u.id as user_id 
    ,u.username
    ,u2.id as friend_id
    ,u2.username as friendname
  FROM user u
  INNER JOIN friend f ON (u.id = f.uid)
  LEFT JOIN user u2 ON (u2.id = f.fid)
  WHERE 'saturngod' = u.username
```

If you want one row per user you can do:

```
  SELECT 
    u.id as user_id 
    ,u.username
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(u2.id) AS friend_ids
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) as friendnames
  FROM user u
  INNER JOIN friend f ON (u.id = f.uid)
  LEFT JOIN user u2 ON (u2.id = f.fid)
  WHERE 'saturngod' = u.username  <<-- optional
  GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: not working. it can only check user.id = friend.uid. It didn't check user.id = friend.fid. example , userid 1 friend are 2 and 3. Your code only search 2 and didn't show 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_id="$id" THEN friend_id ELSE user_id END AS friendID 
FROM user_friend WHERE user_id="$id" OR friend_id="$id" order by friendID ASC
```

Comment: You might add some text to describe what you are doing.